# h1b lottery procedure change to increase proportion of masters. Can someone explain how the expected proportion is different in the new procedure?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, expected-value

Simply speaking, there are 85,000 spots. 20,000 is reserved for masters(or higher education). Previously, they were selecting 20k first from everyone with a masters and then grouping everyone remaining to select 65k randomly.

Recently, they changed the procedure to select 65k first from everyone and then looking at the remaining people with masters to select 20k. They claim this increases the proportion of people with masters in the final list of 85k. At first glance it seems like the proportion of masters vs non-masters should be the same, which maybe it is not. How would you show it mathematically? (assume totally random selection with no biases in the selection in a group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there are $n_1$ people with masters (or higher) applying, $n_2$ people without, and that $n_1,n_2 \geq 85000$ (to avoid details about running out of people).

Method 1 takes $20000$ people with masters, and then $65000$ from the remaining $n_1-20000+n_2$. The proportion of people with masters in the second selection has expectation $p_1 = \frac{n_1-20000}{n_1-20000+n_2}$. The expected number of masters selected in the second half is $p_1*65000$. Therefore the total expected number selected with a masters is $20000+ 65000*\frac{n_1-20000}{n_1+n_2-20000}$.

Method 2 performs the random selection first. The expected proportion selected is $p_2 = \frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$. It can easily be shown that $p_2 > p_1$. The total expected number selected with a masters in method 2 is $20000 + 65000*\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$

Comment: yea that makes sense!  thanks